# Array in Java beginner

Tags: java, arrays, string, command-line

I'm a beginner in coding. We write a project that convert degree from F to C and C to F by using command line argument. Here is what I got so far:

```
public class Implementation 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        {
        String[] days = {"Very Cold", "Cold", "Mild", "Very Mild", "Warm", "Very Warm", "Hot"};
        }
        }
        if (args.length != 3)
        {
            System.out.println("Error! Please try again.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            double degree;
            String celsius;
            String fahrenheit;

            degree = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
            celsius = args[1]; 
            fahrenheit = args[2];                 
        switch (celsius)    
        {
            case "c":
            System.out.printf("%n%s Celsius is %s Fahrenheit\n", args[0], ( 5.0 / 9.0 * (degree - 32)));
                break;
            case "f":
            System.out.printf("%n%s Fahrenheit is %s Celsius\n", args[0], ( 9.0 / 5.0 * (degree + 32)));
                break;
        }
        }
    }
}
```

We have range for degree:

> Below 0 degrees = Very cold
>
> From 0 to 32 = Cold
>
> From 33 to 50 = Mild
>
> From 51 to 60 = Very mild
>
> From 61 to 70 = Warm
>
> From 71 to 90 = Very warm
>
> Above 90 = Hot

I have question about array. How do we show up the array in the output depend on the specific degree? Please and Thank you very much!

Comment: so on output you want to say the temperature and if its "very Cold" or "Cold" etc?

Comment: Just code a nested if

Answer (score 1):

You defined days in its own scope, that's why it's not accessible:

```
    {
    String[] days = {"Very Cold", "Cold", "Mild", "Very Mild", "Warm", "Very Warm", "Hot"};
    }
```

Simply remove the curly braces around it.

```
    String[] days = {"Very Cold", "Cold", "Mild", "Very Mild", "Warm", "Very Warm", "Hot"};
```

Comment: I tried this way but it doesn't recognize **days[n]**. Please help

Comment: Thank you very much. But I came up with a different problem. It makes me to initialize variable n, and when I set up that `int n = 0;`. It just shows up "Cold".

Comment: One more thing, I want the output looks similar to this
`100 degrees Celsius is equal to 212 degrees Fahrenheit ***Hot ***`

Answer (score 0):

There also seems to be one extra curly brace just before `if (args.length != 3)`

```
} //This is extra
        if (args.length != 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, you should just created nested if statements. I found it easier to do this in a separate method that can be called from both cases. Tough I don't you'd apply same "hotness classifications" to Celcius and Fahrenheit degrees, heh!

```
public class Implementation 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {

            if (args.length != 3)
            {
                System.out.println("Error! Please try again.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                double degree;
                String celsius;
                String fahrenheit;

                degree = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
                celsius = args[1]; 
                fahrenheit = args[2];                 

                switch (celsius)    
                {
                case "c":
                  System.out.printf("%n%s Celsius is %s Fahrenheit\n", args[0], ( 5.0 / 9.0 * (degree - 32)));
                  //As the method return string (from the string array 'days') the string can just be printed out.
                  System.out.println( howCold( 5.0 / 9.0 * (degree - 32) ));
                case "f":
                  System.out.printf("%n%s Fahrenheit is %s Celsius\n", args[0], ( 9.0 / 5.0 * (degree + 32)));
                  System.out.println( howCold( 9.0 / 5.0 * (degree + 32) ));
                }

            }
        }

        //Separate method
        //The method takes the converted temperature (d) as a parameter.
        public static String howCold(double d){

          String[] days = {"Very Cold", "Cold", "Mild", "Very Mild", "Warm", "Very Warm", "Hot"};

          if(d < 0){
            return days[0];
          }
          if(d >= 0 && d <= 32){
            return days[1];
          }

          //And so on...

          }
          else{
            return days[6];
          }
        }
    }
```

It's not necessary to use array tough, as you could just return a string:

```
if(d < 0){
   return "Very cold";
}
```